# how to implement a flask sqlalchemy query using a query that is passed into a function

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql-python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert this mysql query into flask sqlalchemy:

```
    SELECT * FROM (*results query*) AS someDocuments WHERE agency in (SELECT agency FROM document WHERE agency ='Comptroller');
```

i'm trying to do this within a function refine_search where a user sends in a results query as a parameter, containing fields such as agency. I've tried

```
    refined = db.session.query(results).filter(results.agency.in_(db.session.query(Document.agency).filter(Document.agency == 'Comptroller')))
```

but i get the error

```
    InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x0331B930>'
```

I have tried

```
    refined = db.session.query(Document).filter(Document.agency.in_(db.session.query(results).filter(results.agency == 'Comptroller')))
```

but i get a similar error

```
InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x0267B2D0>'
```

I have also tried

```
    refined = db.session.query(Document).filter(results.agency.in_(db.session.query(Document.agency).filter(Document.agency == 'Comptroller')))
```

but i get the error

```
   AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'agency'
```

when doing so.

I'm very confused as to how to create this query using flask sqlalchemy syntax